# mySQL : Syntax Error "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, pycharm

I'm trying to perform an outer left join from two subsets, order the results and then inject it into an existing table (append).
I can't get why it's an unacceptable SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO f_grades ( tenant_code, 
                       effective_date, 
                       member_id, 
                       segment_code, 
                       ps_grade 
                      )
(
 SELECT TT.*
 FROM (
       SELECT T.tenant_code as tenant_code,
              COALESCE(T.effective_date, CURRENT_DATE()) as effective_date,
              T.member_id as member_id,
              T.segment_code as segment_code,
              T.ps_grade as ps_grade
       FROM (
               (
                 SELECT tenant_code, 
                        member_id, 
                        segment_code
                 FROM f_grades
                 WHERE effective_date = ( select MAX(DATE(effective_date)) from f_grades )
                  ) as A
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN
                (
                  SELECT partner_member_id, 
                         effective_date, 
                         ps_grade
                  FROM touchpoint.PT_Flags
                 ) as B  on A.member_id = B.partner_member_id
             ) as T
      ) as TT
);
```

The output error:

```
[2021-12-09 22:38:42] [42000][1064] (conn=1151) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'T
[2021-12-09 22:38:42] [42000][1064] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'T
[2021-12-09 22:38:42] ) as TT
[2021-12-09 22:38:42] )' at line 15
```

```
can please someone advise?
```

Comment: `as T` is wrong. Remove it. Refer to columns of subqueries A and B, not T.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need those subqueries. You can just directly the join the two tables.

```
INSERT INTO f_grades (tenant_code, effective_date, member_id, segment_code, ps_grade)
 SELECT A.tenant_code                              as tenant_code,
        COALESCE(B.effective_date, CURRENT_DATE()) as effective_date,
        T.member_id                                as member_id,
        T.segment_code                             as segment_code,
        B.ps_grade                                 as ps_grade
 FROM f_grades A
 LEFT OUTER JOIN touchpoint.PT_Flags B
   ON A.member_id = B.partner_member_id
 WHERE effective_date = (select MAX(DATE(effective_date)) from f_grades)
```